# Spring security custom authentication manager throws exception

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to implement a light weight authentication manager. I'm having a tough time tracking down the issue. Usually the type of exception that I'm currently getting is related to some missing dependency, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

```
WARNING: Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Feb 05 00:51:15 PST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1057)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1010)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:549)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:143)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4831)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5478)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:618)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1498)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:619)
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:566)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1454)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:74)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1295)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1387)
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:818)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

...

```
<security:http create-session="stateless" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
    <security:http-basic />
    <security:custom-filter ref="restFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</security:http>

<!-- implements org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean -->
<bean id="restFilter" class="http.security.RestSecurityFilter">
    <constructor-arg name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="restAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- implements org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider -->
<bean id="restAuthenticationProvider" class="http.security.RestAuthenticationProvider" />
```

When I comment out my security.xml my application starts to work correctly again.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think the error is related to some missing dependency. Try adding these dependencies.
You might be missing spring security config jar.

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```